# Override Module_ConfigurableProduct/final_price.phtml file in theme in magento 2

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, I have to override final_price.phtml file into my theme.

```
vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
```

I tried via override in theme by same folder structure like

```
/app/design/frontend/Company/Theme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/Product/Price/final_price.phtml
```

And also i tried by module. But i am getting this  [error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YrU2bts6FZxvZ9h3VOS9gHLTIYgSrCpz/view)

Please Help
Thank You

Comment: Nobody is there who knows /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have made some capital small type mistake

you have to update file path

> /app/design/frontend/Company/Theme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/Product/Price/final_price.phtml

to

> /app/design/frontend/Company/Theme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml